# HTTP basic auth fails on Restkit, works with AFNetwork

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit, afnetworking

Im trying to make a post request to a server with basic authentification. I tried it with the AFNetwork Library and it works! Because I want to use Restkit and already used if for a lot of things I tried to do the same with it, but it doesnt work. My code looks like that:

```
    RKClient *client = [[RKClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:URL];
    client.username = @"username";
    client.password = @"password";
    client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic;
    client.disableCertificateValidation = YES;


    RKRequest *request = [client post:@"mypath" params:nil delegate:self];
    [request sendSynchronously];
```

But in the delegate

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
```

I always get the error:

> NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You
>   might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be #######
>   HIDDEN ####### which could put your confidential information at risk.,
>   _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?

But I set the

> disableCertificationValidation

to YES

I also tried to follow the information here [RestKit Pull](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/131). But that was also not helpful at all. Has anybody an idea, what can be wrong? With the AFNetwork Library the code is more or less the same, but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, I did not get my solution over RestKit. I tried everything, also added the certificates with addRootCertificates, but RestKit always get the same error.
In the end, I did it on my own.

```
NSData* certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyCert" ofType:@"cer"]];

[FileUtility addCertToKeychain:certData];
```

Method addCertToKeychain:

```
#pragma mark SSL Certification Methods
+ (void) addCertToKeychain:(NSData*)certInDer
{
    OSStatus            err = noErr;
    SecCertificateRef   cert;

    cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) certInDer);
    assert(cert != NULL);

    CFTypeRef result;

    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          (__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate, kSecClass,
                          cert, kSecValueRef,
                          nil];

    err = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dict, &result);
    assert(err == noErr || err == errSecDuplicateItem);

    CFRelease(cert);
}
```

Probably it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to RestKit as well, but I just got HTTP Basic Auth to work, mainly using your example and these two changes:

- You don't need `disableCertificateValidation` for Basic Auth, as this method is only needed when you work with SSL connections. So remove that one.
- As you are sending the request synchronously, you don't need a delegate or receiver method and you can simply evaluate your response one line of code later.

If it still doesn't work, check if your URL is ultimately right, by adding `NSLog(@"URL: %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);` between your request initialization and `sendSynchronously`

Hope this helps, it worked for me.

Comment: I should need disableCertificateValidation, because I have SSL connections. I tried everything, also added the certificates with addRootCertificate in RestKit. Everything didnt help. At least I added the certificates on my own, without the RestKit API.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was setting disableCertificateValidation on RKClient but I was using a RKObjectManager which used a different RKClient. The following line did the trick:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.disableCertificateValidation = YES;
```